# Console Application Interval vs Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, console-application, thread-sleep

I have a console application which should periodically listen remote database,
if there is a new value then do some stuff.

Normally I create windows task scheduler job to run this console app every 2 minutes.
Another option I think, in console app I will have a code like;

```
while(true)
{
  ConnectDatabaseAndProcess();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120000);
}
```

So I assume console app will be always open, and will wait 2 minutes for every process and continue.
In performance matter will it make any difference?

Comment: Performance is likely negligible. If the application were to crash, however, the task scheduler would just try to launch it again in 2 minutes. With `Thread.Sleep`, it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your computer is so overloaded that the time to create a process every two minutes is a huge drain on resources, there's no benefit to having your program sitting in a loop waiting for two minutes, just so that it can poll the database.

The benefit of using scheduled tasks is that you can change the scheduled task frequency (make it once every five minutes, or once an hour, or whatever) without having to modify the program. Sure, you could use an application configuration file, but why? Why duplicate functionality that already exists in the operating system, and is more flexible.

Also, with a scheduled task, you know that the program will start the polling operation again the next time the computer is rebooted. If you depend on the program to provide that delay, you have to either remember to start it every time, or put it in the startup task list.

Also, when the program is sitting there idle, it's occupying memory that could be used by other processes.

All told, using scheduled tasks is a much more flexible and robust solution. Any marginal performance gain (and we're talking, at most, one second) from having the program always running is far outweighed by the disadvantages.